# Type error: memory is not implicitly convertible to expected type

Tags: solidity, contract-development, storage, memory

I have a function that returns a list of `BetProposition` smart contracts:

```
function getBetsForMatchup(uint matchupIdentifier) public returns (BetProposition[]) {
        return bets[matchupIdentifier];
    }
```

Later I initialize a local variable array as such, so I can loop through them:

```
   BetProposition[] betsToCancel = getBetsForMatchup(matchupIdentifier);
```

However, this doesn't seem to work and I get this error:

```
TypeError: Type contract BetProposition[] memory is not implicitly convertible to expected type contract BetProposition[] storage pointer.
    BetProposition[] betsToCancel = getBetsForMatchup(matchupIdentifier);
    ^------------------------------------------------------------------^
```

I'm not totally sure what this means. Any help appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

The compiler thinks you are trying to store the return value of getBetsForMatchup in contract (permanent) storage.

Try changing

```
   BetProposition[] betsToCancel = getBetsForMatchup(matchupIdentifier);
```

to

```
   BetProposition[] memory betsToCancel = getBetsForMatchup(matchupIdentifier);
```

This compiled on remix:

```
   pragma solidity ^0.4.20;
   contract BetProposition {
       uint public somevar;

       function BetProposition(uint _some) public {
         somevar = _some;
       }
   }

   contract Tester2 {
        mapping(uint => BetProposition[]) bets;

        function getBetsForMatchup(uint matchupIdentifier) public view returns (BetProposition[]) {
            return bets[matchupIdentifier];
        }

        function other(uint matchupIdentifier) public view returns(uint) {
             uint total = 0;
             BetProposition[] memory betsToCancel = getBetsForMatchup(matchupIdentifier);
             for (uint i = 0; i < betsToCancel.length; i++) {
                 total = total + betsToCancel[i].somevar();
             }
             return total;
        }
}
```

Comment: Is this a relatively new feature? I get the following error now: UnimplementedFeatureError: Copying of type struct BetCard.Matchup memory[3] memory to storage not yet supported.

Comment: I updated my response with a sample I was able to compile on remix.  Note, this is using solidity ^0.4.20.  Also, if you are trying to call getBetsForMatchup externally (ie from javascript) you will run into trouble as functions returning contract types isn't supported via the abi.

Comment: @Howard, is that where "pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2" comes in?  You get warned not to use it in production, but it's worth a try depending on how it's being used.

Comment: That pragma works for returning structs, not sure about contracts refs.  Its certainly useful, so long as you are in full control of your client.